# How can I speed up raw data computation

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I have the temperature according to x,y,z as raw data.

I want to turn the raw data of x, y, z, t into grid data.

When transforming data by applying t values to the x and z coordinates according to z, I created a zero array and converted it into a pandas data frame.

Afterwards, the data was processed by changing the value in each position using the for statement, which takes a very long time.

In the case of 100x100, the for loop is repeated 10000 times and it takes 16 s to 20 s.
I want less computation time.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

```
data = Data_load()

resolution = 100
step = 100 / resolution
zero = np.zeros((100,100))
zero_df = pd.DataFrame(zero)

for x in zero_df.index:
    for y in zero_df.columns:
        data.query('z == 0.25')
        t_data = data.query('{}< x <={} and {} < y <= {}'.format(x, x+step, y, y+step))

        if len(t_data) != 0:
            t = np.sum(t_data['T']) / len(t_data)
            zero_df[x][y] = t
      
print(zero_df)
print(np.max(zero_df))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(zero_df, cmap='jet',vmin=1000, vmax=2000)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Layer : {}'.format(0.25))
ax.set_ylim(100, 0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

data example

```
             x       y     z    c    a       T
32      16.300  15.501  0.00  0.0  0.0  1652.1
33      16.833  15.501  0.00  0.0  0.0  1750.2
34      17.367  15.501  0.00  0.0  0.0  1719.9
35      17.900  15.501  0.00  0.0  0.0  1714.4
36      18.433  15.501  0.00  0.0  0.0  1706.3
...        ...     ...   ...  ...  ...     ...
238242  84.500  84.500  9.75  0.0  0.0  1449.6
238243  84.500  84.500  9.75  0.0  0.0  1446.7
238244  84.510  84.500  9.75  0.0  0.0  1317.4
238245  84.510  84.500  9.75  0.0  0.0  1251.9
238246  84.510  84.500  9.75  0.0  0.0  1221.5
```

Comment: `data = Data_load()`. Please generate sample data to be reproducible.

Comment: sorry, added my data example

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first I would create the temporary dataset with given `z`

```
t_data = data[data['z']==0.25]
```

Then, I would create a new, transformed coordinates (if you would like to have resolution 1, 0.1, 0.01 it's quite easy):

```
t_data['x_new'] = t_data['x'].round(0)
t_data['y_new'] = t_data['y'].round(0)
```

Else, you would have to create your own "rounder", f.e. with https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html

Then I would group the data based on the new coordinates and calculate the mean in new coordinates.

```
t_data_gridded = t_data.groupby(('x_new', 'y_new'))['T'].mean().reset_index()
```

If not all of the datapoints are in your grid you will have to join it to prepared grid:

```
from itertools import product
zero_df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(range(0,100,1), range(0,100,1))), columns=('x', 'y'))
zero_df = zero_df.merge(t_data_gridded['x_new', 'y_new', 'T'], 
             left_on=('x', 'y'), 
             right_on=('x_new', 'y_new'), 
             how = "left")
```

And finally, create the pivoted matrix (if it is needed):

```
zero_df.pivot_table(values='T', index='x', columns='y')
```

It's a lot of operations, but it should be significantly faster (you are not making loops).

Comment: thank you. I think that good code can be developed by referring to your code.